# Retornando(Null) ao mostrar uma varíavel String

Tags: c, null

O programa deve receber o nome de uma pessoa e o sexo e mostre os dados digitados pelo usuário, porém quando o programa mostra o nome que digitei está aparecendo Null em vez de mostrar o nome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char nome, sexo;

    printf("Digite o seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &nome);
    printf("Digite o seu sexo M (Masculino) ou F (Feminino): ");
    scanf("%s", &sexo);

    if(sexo=='f' || sexo=='F')
    {
        printf("\nOlá %s o seu sexo é feminino.\n\n", nome);
    }else

    if(sexo=='m' ||sexo=='M')
    {
        printf("\nOlá %s o seu sexo é masculino.\n\n", nome);
    }else

    if(sexo!='f' || sexo!='F' || sexo!='m' || sexo!='M')
    {
        printf("Sexo inválido");
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

[image: Imagem do Erro]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sexo` é do tipo `char`, ok, basta um caractere para armazená-lo, pelo menos na forma usada. Mas tem um erro na leitura dele. Para ler um dado `char` [usa-se o `%c` no `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Já no nome está usando a formatação correta no `scanf()`, mas está usando o tipo errado na variável. Um nome precisa ser uma *string*, portanto uma sequência se caracteres terminado por um nulo. Você só está pegando o nulo porque não declarou a variável como uma sequência e sim como um único caractere.

Para declarar uma sequência usamos um ponteiro ou um *array*. Neste caso me parece ser mais adequado um *array* para ele reservar o espaço para a variável toda. Então seria algo como `char nome[31]`. Aí nem precisa passar o endereço porque um *array* já é um endereço de memória, já é uma referência.

De forma mais organizada o código fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    char nome[31];
    char sexo;
    printf("Digite o seu nome: ");
    scanf("%30s", nome);
    printf("Digite o seu sexo M (Masculino) ou F (Feminino): ");
    scanf("%c", &sexo);
    if (sexo == 'f' ||  sexo == 'F') printf("\nOlá %s o seu sexo é feminino.", nome);
    else if (sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M') printf("\nOlá %s o seu sexo é masculino.", nome);
    else printf("Sexo inválido");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/DataEntry.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Você está declarando `nome` como sendo um `char`:

```
char nome, sexo;
```

Existem duas alternativas. A primeira é você declarar a variável como um *vetor*, onde definirá o tamanho máximo de caracteres que ela pode armazenar; outra é utilizar um *ponteiro*, tornando isso mais dinâmico.

```
//opção usando vetor
char nome[256];
//opção usando ponteiro
char *nome;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo.

Answer (score 2):

Voce tem que declarar o char como um vetor:

```
char[numero] nome;
```